# Show that the only point in the interior of triangle ABC that is its own isogonal conjugate is the incenter.

Tags: proof-verification, euclidean-geometry

**Also: Find all other points in the plane that are their own isogonal conjugates.**

It seems quite obvious that in order for an isogonal conjugate to be itself it must also be the incenter, because it is constructed using angle bisectors - so angle bisectors would reflect to be themselves, but how would I show this formally?

Also, are there any other points on the plane that are their own isogonal conjugates? I would imagine only origins of excircles but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Hint: let your triangle be $ABC$ and the point considered $P$. Which points satisfy that the reflection of $AP$ in bisector of $BAC$ is $AP$ again?

Comment: Only points on the angle bisectors of BAC reflect AP onto the angle bisectors again. Similarly, if we looked at point P from BP the same holds. So is that strong enough to argue that the only point inside of the triangle that is its own isogonal conjugate must be the incenter?

Comment: Yes, that's enough. $P$ must lie on all internal angle bisectors, so it must be incenter. In a similar way you can figure out what points outside get mapped to themselves.

Comment: What is the point outside? The vertices of each excircle? Which also fall on the angle bisectors, just two exterior and one interior?

Comment: That's precisely it (btw, it's _center_ of a circle, not a vertex ;) )